# Typescript type from an array

Tags: typescript

Say I have:

```
const generate = (array: string[]) => {
   const obj: any = {};
   array.map(a => a.toUpperCase()].forEach(a => obj[a] = a);

   return obj;
}
```

So that I can do:

```
const constants = generate(['foo', 'bar']);
constants.FOO;
constants.BAR;
```

Is there anyway to define the type so that `constants.BAZ` for example errors out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to perform string transformation operations like `toUpperCase` / `toLowerCase` in the TypeScript type system

Comment: Okay what if we forget the text transformation? If I provide `['foo', 'bar']` I want to get `constant.foo` and `constant.bar`

Comment: @Kousha Something like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20generate%3CK%20extends%20string%3E(...keys%3A%20K%5B%5D)%3A%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20K%5D%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20obj%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20keys.forEach(k%20%3D%3E%20obj%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20k)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20obj%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20constants%20%3D%20generate(%22foo%22%2C%20%22bar%22)%3B%0D%0Aconstants.foo%3B%0D%0Aconstants.bar%3B%0D%0Aconstants.baz%3B)?

Comment: Yes that works great thanks! Can you post it here and I'll mark this as +1

Comment: There is now! https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types

Answer (score 0):

Ryans answer is great and if I may expand on it since you cannot make it a const but you can do this:

```
function generate<K extends string>(...keys: K[]): { [P in K]: P; } {
    const obj: any = {};
    keys.forEach(k => obj[k] = k;
    return obj;
}

const constants = generate("foo", "bar");
constants.foo;
constants.bar;
constants.baz; // fails because key is not in K
constants.foo = "fo"; // fails because value is not same as key.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Okay what if we forget the text transformation? If I provide `['foo', 'bar']` I want to get `constant.foo` and `constant.bar`

Yes, this can be achieved using type arguments and map types:

```
function generate<K extends string>(...keys: K[]): { [P in K]: string; } {
    const obj: any = {};
    keys.forEach(k => obj[k] = k);
    return obj;
}

const constants = generate("foo", "bar");
constants.foo; // string
constants.bar; // string
constants.baz; // Error
```

(I used a rest argument for no particular reason, you could make it a single array arg of the same `K[]` type.)